# Acces response header angular 7 in flatMap

Tags: angular

I'm try access the reponse header inside flatMap

```
this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>(`${environment.URL_API}/patients/v1/`, patient, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
  flatMap((res: any) => {
    console.log(res)
    var location = res.headers.get('Location'); //location = null
    console.log("service", location)
    return this.find(location);
  }),
  map(a => {
    return a
  }));
```

but `res.headers.get('Location')` is undefined

[image]

In console the chrome there is a Header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in the backend:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ... ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ... ");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Custom-header");
header("X-Custom-header: $some data");
```

Then on front end this worked fine:

```
this.httpClientObject.get(url).toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                let data = res.headers.get('X-Custom-header');
                console.log(data);
            })
```

Exactly, this is not an Angular issue. Is an API problem. With the header

```
'access-control-expose-headers' : 'name-of-expose-header'
```

works fine.

The problem is that this doesn't work with the header

```
'access-control-expose-headers' : '*'
```

You can't use * and you have to put explicity the name of the headers that you want to expose.

Please see [access-control-expose-headers](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237) issue